# How to remove authorizer from API gateway websocket API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway v2 websocket API, which used to utilize a lambda authorizer for my $connect route, but I now need to remove it and handle authorization in another way.
I've removed the Authorizer from the $connect route and re-deployed my API. I've verified that the API in API gateway no longer has an attached authorizer, and that the $connect integration says "Auth: NONE".

However, when I try to connect to my websocket it still behaves as if there is an authorizer connected - if a token is present, the socket is connected and I get a log entry in CloudWatch on my connect lambda (which contains an authorizer context as if the authorizer lambda had still been called!), and if a token is NOT present, I get a 1006 error and no traces of any connect invocation in my cloudwatch logs at all.

It's as if removing an authorizer from an existing API does not work, because although the AWS console shows no traces of any authorizer being present in the API, it behaves exactly as before I removed the authorizer.
(I have double checked that I'm calling the correct API and similar stupid mistakes.)

Could this be a bug in API gateway?
How can I debug it further, as I get no other log entries than my connect lambda when it DOES pass authorization - but what I want is to completely remove the authorization lambda!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so wise from previous experience I thought "what if the API has to be deployed from the console again", so I tried that, and then I got the error message that $default route is missing an integration.

My API is several years old. My best guess is that when it was created, it was legal to deploy APIs without a default route integration, but nowadays it isn't. The CloudFormation template deployed without error but the `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api` resource apparently wasn't updated properly!

The next problem was that I wasn't allowed to add a $default route to my API since it already exists an implicit one, so I created a $default route with a stupid empty MOCK integration manually in the console and then had to make sure my CF template was in sync.

Definitely not easy to debug errors like this!